# How to access my app’s derived data folder itself?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager, xcode-build-settings

I’m in the middle of moving my iOS app’s Firebase dependency from CocoaPods to Swift Package Manager.

Firebase’s Crashlytics requires a script to be executed while the app is building (using the Run Script build phase). Back in the CocoaPods days, I used to call the script the way [documented by Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started): `"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"`.

After I’ve switched to SPM, Firebase files are no longer in `${PODS_ROOT}`, and there’s no such variable available at all. I know the file I need is now located in the `DerivedData` folder, specifically it’s at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-abcde/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run`. The problem is, **the `MyApp-abcde` folder is not easily referenced.**

[A Medium post I found](https://medium.com/dev-genius/firebase-spm-xcode-12-bcefcef2bd6b) suggested using the `${BUILD_DIR}` build variable (in regard to the example above, it would resolve to `<…>/MyApp-abcde/Build/Products`), and calling the `dirname` command to move up the directory hierarchy.

This hack worked only for *running* the app. When I tried to *archive* it, `${BUILD_DIR}` resolved to another path, namely `<…>/MyApp-abcde/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath`. I tried a few more build variables, such as `${SYMROOT}`, in place of `${BUILD_DIR}`, but they also produce different paths depending on the operation.

So, here comes the question…

**Is there a way to reliably reference my app’s derived data folder’s root** (i.e. `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-abcde`) **using Xcode’s build variables?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You were close. This should work:

```
${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run
```

Comment: The path you have seems to work for both Run and Archive actions. Thank you so much!

Comment: For Xcode Server Bots (Xcode 12.4 era) use:  `${XCS_DERIVED_DATA_DIR%/*}/Dependencies/checkouts`

Answer (score 2):

**Crashlytics run script**

To build&run from Xcode:

```
${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run
```

To archive for distribution from Xcode Server at CI/CD:

```
${XCS_DERIVED_DATA_DIR%/*}/Dependencies/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run
```

To work for both at the same time:

```
if [[ "${XCS_DERIVED_DATA_DIR}" == "" ]]; then
  ${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run
else
  ${XCS_DERIVED_DATA_DIR%/*}/Dependencies/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm reworking my answer as I realized I haven't answered your question..

I have a run script that copies the build targets into a new folder. This works for both Build and Archive. Note that you need the -L on copy to follow the symlink

```
# Copy the built framework into a sibling to the project folder
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]]; then
  mkdir -p "$PROJECT_DIR/../../iwins-ios-sdk/debug"
  rm -rf "$PROJECT_DIR/../../iwins-ios-sdk/debug/IWiNS_SDK.framework"
  cp -LR "$BUILD_DIR/Debug-iphoneos/IWiNS_SDK.framework" "$PROJECT_DIR/../../iwins-ios-sdk/debug"
else
  mkdir -p "$PROJECT_DIR/../../iwins-ios-sdk/release"
  rm -rf "$PROJECT_DIR/../../iwins-ios-sdk/release/IWiNS_SDK.framework"
  cp -LR "$BUILD_DIR/Release-iphoneos/IWiNS_SDK.framework" "$PROJECT_DIR/../../iwins-ios-sdk/release"
fi
```

Also, you can find all of the build envvars here:
https://gist.github.com/gdavis/6670468

So, it appears that $BUILD_DIR is different for build/release, but by copying the files to a known location at build time, you'll know where to find them.